# PowerShell: Regex: Unrecognized escape sequence

Tags: regex, powershell

Operating System - **Windows 10**

Powershell version - **5.1.15063.1088**

Below is my regex101 working expression

```
"System.Title":"([a-zA-Z0-9\:\s\(\)\"\+\-\\\/\_\.\-]*)"
```

[image]
[image]

As it can be seen from the above, regex perfectly captures Group[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX8g7.png). However, in PowerShell ISE I can't use the same regex expression

```
The string "System.Title":"([a-zA-Z0-9\:\s\(\)\"\+\-\\\/\_\.\-]*)" is not a valid regular expression: parsing ""System.Title":"([a-zA-Z0-9\:\s\(\)\"\+\-\\\/\_\.\-]*)"" - Unrecognized 
escape sequence \_.
```

Image below

[image]

According to the advise from the error message, the problem with unrecognized escape sequence `\_` but it's perfectly working fine in regex101. Has anyone else faced these types of errors before with PowerShell?

> The duplicative answer refers to C#, and this question regarding
>   PowerShell ISE platform.

Comment: Escaping `_` in .NET regex is an error. It is not an error in PCRE

Comment: Would never guess that, especially that duplicative answer refers to C#, and I don't know much about C#

Comment: You don't need to escape `_` to include it in a `[ ]` block

Comment: So not all the variations of regex that are being tried in regex101 will work in PowerShell ISE correct?

Comment: First, my personal recommendation is to avoid testing code in the ISE. I recommend always running code in an actual powershell console even if you are writing it in the ISE. Second, there are several different regex engines in existence and they all behave slightly differently from each other so you should always be sure of which engine any given tester/emmulator is using. As far as I know, Powershell uses the .Net engine but it has been so many years since I read Mastering Regular Expressions that I don't remember what is special about the .Net engine.

Comment: Powershell uses .NET regex library, same as C#, VB.NET, etc. When you want to learn about Powershell regex, you should always search for .NET regex. It is the same regex library, thus closed as a dupe. Besides, regex101 does not support .NET regex syntax, and it makes no sense even mentioning it in the context of .NET regex.

Comment: that's the reason I'm really tired of programming...

Comment: When it comes to regex: Never do "precautionary escaping". Escape exactly what you need to escape, and not a single character more. Yes, that requires knowing what regex dialect you are dealing with and how strings work in the language that regex dialect is integrated into. There are .NET regex testers out there ([for example](http://regexstorm.net/tester)), you can build and test a pattern in one of them. You could also use REPL tools like LINQpad, but there you'd have to deal with diverging string requirements (.NET string literals and Powershell string literals work differently).

Comment: This seems to work reasonably well: [regexstorm link](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22System.Title%22%3a%22%28%5b%5cw%3a%5cs%28%29-%5c%5c%22%2f_.%2b-%5d*%3f%29%22%2c&i=%22other.stuff%22%3a%22foo%22%2c%0d%0a%22System.Title%22%3a%22sdasdsd+%5c%22asd+asd+%0d%0asad%5c%22+%28ada%29+_sd%2b%22%2c%0d%0a%22other.stuff%22%3a%22foo%22%2c%0d%0a), note the required comma at the end and the non-greedy star.